# how to install previous version of xarray

Tags: python-xarray

I am reading other's pickle file that may have data type based on xarray. Now I cannot read in the pickle file with the error "No module named core.dataset".

I guess this maybe a xarray issue. My collaborator asked me to change my version to his version and try again.

My version is 0.8.2, and his version 0.8.0. So how can I change back to his version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use "conda install xarray==0.8.0" if you're using anaconda, or "pip install xarray==0.8.0" otherwise.

Comment: Is there any way to load the xarray without rolling back the package version? Can I install old versions with different names? And is there an easy way to see which version is needed if I don't know?

Comment: I don't know. I am actually in a "hello world" level of python. However, I guess your last question is negative. As I heard from a python developer, it is indeed very time consuming to deal with these kind of things (versions, dependencies, dependencies of dependencies, dependencies of dependencies of dependencies, when doing installation).